# What is the best way to load data inside a Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, ios7, viewcontroller

I'm writing an iOS app that is getting data from a server. I have several `ViewControllers`. I used to load data for that viewcontroller under the `viewDidLoad` method

```
-(void)ViewDidload
{
    [self loadData];
}


-(void)loadData
{
    //calling to webservice caller class
}
```

But this reduces the app's performance. What is the best method to load data within a viewcontroller? For webservice callings, I have a seperate class. Within my `loadData` method I call to that particular method inside the webservice calling class.

This is going to block my UI.

Comment: what do you mean with "this reduces the app performance". Your app is lagging when you are calling your webservice? This is not because you are calling that in `viewDidLoad` this is because you are doing that in the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with "*this reduces the app performance*". Your app is lagging when you are calling your webservice? This is not because you are calling that in `viewDidLoad` this is because you are doing that in the main thread.

To call your webservice you can use:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

// Call here your web service

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // push here the results to your ViewController

    });

});
```

With this simple solution you are downloading data from your webservice in a separate thread. And pushing the data to your `ViewController` with the mainThread. This code is not freezing your app. However you will have a moment that nothing happens. This is a good moment to use a `UIActivityIndicatorVew`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your interface is lagging.
Try this:

```
-(void)ViewDidload
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```